# Method not performing correctly

Tags: java

I have a method in my Util class that used to work but however for some reason it is not working. I am All variables accessed by the class are static and are in the same class, however it prints out wrong. My question could be answered simply if the problem is simple

```
public static List<Integer> superMaleList = new ArrayList<>();
int REDO_LISTS = 2;

public static void runRefresh(int runcode)
{

    if (runcode == REDO_LISTS)
    {
        Log.i("RUN REFRESH", " " + superMaleList.size()); //Prints out correct size

        refresh(runcode, superMaleList);
    }
}

public static void refresh(int runcode, List maleList)
{
    Log.i("RUN REFRESH", ""+ maleList.size()); //prints incorrectly
}
```

These methods are accessed staticly in another class. I can add to the list and read from the list in other classes, however when I pass the list variable to these methods, they do not print correctly. Why?

**UPDATE**

The way I use these methods are as follows (this is performed staticly in a thread)

```
EventUtils.superMaleList.add(2);
EventUtils.runRefresh(2);
```

Comment: Hm...probably some multithreading problem?

Comment: Please don't use raw types. And without `REDO_LISTS` being static this code won't compile.

Comment: Can you share how do you test these methods?

Comment: Well i thought so too but when I print out the actual list size in the refresh method rather than the passed list size, it prints correctly. And the passed list prints 0;

Comment: @kocko yes I did debug it by checking the list size immediately after I add something to it. After debugging, I have scaled the problem down to this area. It does not seem to be reading the passed list correctly. However, the list in the class contains data. Just when printing out the passed list does it seem to not to contain data.

Comment: I implemented a [simple class](http://pastebin.com/jCZjpJNW) in order to reproduce the problem, but I get the expected results. Are you sure it's not some other thread the cleans the list before the `refresh` method is called?

Comment: @kocko I am sure because if I print in the refresh method Log.i("RUN REFRESH", "" + superMaleList.size()); It will print the correct results. If i print Log.i("RUN REFRESH", "" + maleList.size());, it will print incorrectly.

Comment: If you already used a debugger, then use this tool to check the id/reference of the passed list. If it is the same as `superMaleList` then it got changes somewhere/somehow. If not, then there is a different problem.

Comment: Please post code that demonstrates your problem in a reproducible way. We can't run this, so we can't see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibilities:

1. In a multi-threaded environment, you may be removing elements from `superMaleList` on another thread, calling `clear()` on the list, or re-initializing superMaleList to a new list object. You could prevent the last condition (re-initializing) by making superMaleList a `final` variable.
2. Multiple [class loaders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) can result in more than one superMaleList. Try configuring your application to use a single ClassLoader, to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Calling superMaleList directly in my opinion is bad, i am not sure why you are trying to do this. GKNICKER has stated it perfectly why so you are getting the error.

```
EventUtils.superMaleList.add(2);
EventUtils.runRefresh(2);
```

Suppose there is some thread with

```
EventUtils.superMaleList.add(2);
EventUtils.runRefresh(1);
```

Another element is added but runRefresh will do nothing

Instead of the above you should make superMaleList as private and add elements via some method which is static and synchronized.